# receiving multiple emails in codeigniter booking form

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have a booking form on my codeigniter website. when the user book i got an email, but the problem is that i am receiving 15 email on per booking. I got one email which has the user given information and rest are blank.

Here is my form:

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Booking/booking_mail/<?php echo $row['destination']; ?>/<?php echo $row['fare']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                       <input name="txtname" type="text" class="form-control"  required="required" />




                        <input name="textcel" type="textcel" class="form-control" required="required" />


                        <input name="txtemail" type="email"  class="form-control" name="txtemail" required="required" />



                    <textarea name="txtmessage" rows="2" cols="20" id="txtmessage" class="form-control" name="txtmessage">
</textarea>


                  <input type="submit" name="btnsendmessage" value="Send Message" id="btnsendmessage" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </form>
```

and here is my controller function:

```
function booking_mail(){

        $txtname= $this->input->post('txtname');
        $txtcel= $this->input->post('textcel');
        $txtemail= $this->input->post('txtemail');
        $txtmessage= $this->input->post('txtmessage');
        $destination = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $fare = $this->uri->segment(4);

            $this->load->library('email');
            $this->email->from('turkishairlines.com', $txtname);
            $this->email->to('fantastictravelsuk@gmail.com');
            $this->email->subject('Turkish Airline Booking Form');

            $this->email->message(
            'Name: '.$txtname.'
            Cell No: '.$txtcel.' 
            Email: '.$txtemail.'
            Message: '.$txtmessage.'
            Destination: '.$destination.'
            Fare: '.$fare.''
         );
        $this->email->send();

            $this->load->view('thanks');

    }
```

Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like, when ever you hit page, this send you an email. To avoid this issue, you can check form is posted or not.

Example

```
function booking_mail()
{

    if( isset($_POST['txtemail']) )
    {
        $txtname= $this->input->post('txtname');
        $txtcel= $this->input->post('textcel');
        $txtemail= $this->input->post('txtemail');
        $txtmessage= $this->input->post('txtmessage');
        $destination = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $fare = $this->uri->segment(4);

            $this->load->library('email');
            $this->email->from('turkishairlines.com', $txtname);
            $this->email->to('fantastictravelsuk@gmail.com');
            $this->email->subject('Turkish Airline Booking Form');

            $this->email->message(
            'Name: '.$txtname.'
            Cell No: '.$txtcel.' 
            Email: '.$txtemail.'
            Message: '.$txtmessage.'
            Destination: '.$destination.'
            Fare: '.$fare.''
         );
        $this->email->send();

            $this->load->view('thanks');
    }
    else
        die('form is not posted');

}
```